# Raspberry PI 3 Model B+ Power Supply

Tags: pi-3

I have recently bought Raspberry PI 3 Model B+
Spec says need power supply 5V / 2.5A, whether Moto Turbo Charger with output 5V / 3A can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy the official 5.1Volt 2.5Amp 18 AWG cable power supply.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Looks like that Moto charger will only supply full power to a compatible Motorola phone.

Answer (score 3):

Any 5V power source which can supply sufficient power (amps) may be used.

The Pi will use the power it needs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The MotoTurbo Charger (like most power supplies is a `voltage source`, which means its output voltage is regulated. The amperage specification is just the maximum amount of current the supply can host, and keep its voltage regulated to the spec value.